# How to repeat a test with pytest after every other test?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have few test cases as described below. But i want to repeat test1() after every other test case. how can i achieve this?

```
@pytest.mark.test1()
@pytest.mark.parametrize(a,b,c)
def test_test1():
   ......
   ......

@pytest.mark.test2()
def test_test2():
   ......
   ......

@pytest.mark.test3()
def test_test3():
   ......
   ......

run test1() again
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the list of tests to be executed by implementing the [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hook. Example: In your root dir, create a file named `conftest.py` and add the hook to it:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    test1s = [item for item in items if item.function.__name__ == 'test_test1']
    items.extend(test1s)
```

Now the `test_test1` will be appended to the list of already collected tests, being executed twice:

```
$ pytest -v
============================= test session starts =============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.4.0, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-49213392, inifile:
plugins: celery-4.1.0, forked-0.2, cov-2.5.1, asyncio-0.8.0, xdist-1.22.0, mock-1.6.3, hypothesis-3.44.4
collected 5 items

test_spam.py::test_test1[a] PASSED                                      [ 12%]
test_spam.py::test_test1[b] PASSED                                      [ 25%]
test_spam.py::test_test1[c] PASSED                                      [ 37%]
test_spam.py::test_test2 PASSED                                         [ 50%]
test_spam.py::test_test3 PASSED                                         [ 62%]
test_spam.py::test_test1[a] PASSED                                      [ 62%]
test_spam.py::test_test1[b] PASSED                                      [ 62%]
test_spam.py::test_test1[c] PASSED                                      [ 62%]

========================== 8 passed in 0.02 seconds ===========================
```

A more elegant solution would be using a custom marker, let's name it `my_repeat`:

```
@pytest.mark.my_repeat
@pytest.mark.parametrize(a,b,c)
def test_test1():
    ...
```

Adapted hook in `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    repeats = [item for item in items if item.get_marker('my_repeat')]
    items.extend(repeats)
```